# Is this way of reading the last line in a text file incorrect? python

Tags: python, file, io

Im trying to read the last line of a text file so I came up with this
Is it incorrect?

```
import time
Data = open("Data.txt")
lines = len(Data.readlines())
Data.close() 

print lines

Data = open("Data.txt")

for x in range(0, lines):
    lastline = Data.readline()
#   print lastline


print lastline
```

Comment: What makes you think it's incorrect? What goes wrong or differently than your expectations?

Comment: To expand on what @JoshCaswell said, correct and not optimal are two different things.  If the code does what you intend, it is correct.  There may be better ways to do it, however.  Are you asking if there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the code syntactically speaking, but it could be done much simpler. Using `with` is the suggested way of opening files, it ensures that the file is closed properly once the code exits the scope of the `with` thus simplifying your code.

```
with open("Data.txt") as f:
    # readlines returns a list of lines in the file
    # since it is a list all you need do is access the last element in the list
    # that element should be the last line in your text file.
    last_line = f.readlines()[-1] 

    print last_line
```